# Activity Life Cycle- use in real project

Tags: android, performance

We all know about the `Activity` lifecycle in `Android`? We see `onCreate()` Function in the start when the `Activity` is inflated. Now, how should we code in order to use the states of the `Activity` lifecycle properly so that we don't end up coding everything in `onCreate()`?

Comment: By Knowing which method will called once and which methods can be called multiple times in a lifecycle you can proceed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow some rules to help you decide where to place your code, but this is highly contextual and cannot be used as a rule of thumb:

`onCreate()` -> 
setup your `Activity` `Layout`, global variables and anything which needs to be initialized for your current `Activity`

`onStart()` -> 
register for `BroadcastReceivers` (SMS, Audio), `Service` or any other information you need to subscribe to when your `Activity` has started

`onResume()` ->
Your `Activity` is now visible to user. All your `UI` related things can go here like starting an `Animation` or listeneing to harware info like accelerometer to which your `UI` may react

`onPause()` ->
reverse/stop the affect of `onResume()`

`onStop()` ->
reverse/stop the affect of `onStart()`

`onDestroy()` ->
reverse/stop the affect of `onCreate()`. Free up any resource that you might have acquired

Comment: That is true but in a project, we don,t actually call these methods, do we?